# How to order dialogs?

Tags: html, css, dialog

From what I've read HTML `dialog` does not use `z-index`, it is placed in special top layer above all other elements.

With single dialog it is fine and all, but when two dialogs are shown, how do I say -- "place dialog A over dialog B, always"?

*Just to clarify, I am asking about regular HTML dialogs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/dialog And more info here: https://developer.chrome.com/blog/what-is-the-top-layer/*.